# jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed? A-Z, & @

Tags: javascript, jquery

on a keydown I get the following from jQuery:

```
jQuery.Event
altKey: false
attrChange: undefined
attrName: undefined
bubbles: true
button: undefined
cancelable: true
charCode: 0
clientX: undefined
clientY: undefined
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: HTMLDivElement
data: undefined
detail: 0
eventPhase: 2
fromElement: undefined
handleObj: Object
handler: function () {
isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse() {
jQuery16106168975948821753: true
keyCode: 51
layerX: 0
layerY: 0
metaKey: true
newValue: undefined
offsetX: undefined
offsetY: undefined
originalEvent: KeyboardEvent
pageX: 0
pageY: 0
prevValue: undefined
relatedNode: undefined
relatedTarget: undefined
screenX: undefined
screenY: undefined
shiftKey: false
srcElement: HTMLDivElement
target: HTMLDivElement
timeStamp: 1320206454048
toElement: undefined
type: "keydown"
view: DOMWindow
wheelDelta: undefined
which: 51
__proto__: Object
```

How can I get what key was pressed? I tried:

```
 String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```

That works for A-Z, but if I press @ I don't get @ I get 2?

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three keyboard events you can trap: `keyup`, `keydown`, and `keypress`. The first two behave the way you've observed, and the latter behaves the way you seem to want.

You need to understand the difference between a key and the character(s) associated with that key.

As explained in the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) (admittedly it is kind of buried), the `keyup` and `keydown` events give a keyCode that corresponds to the actual physical key on the keyboard, so uppercase "A" and lowercase "a" will have the same code, as will "2" and "@" - but note that the "2" key above the "W" has a different code to the "2" key on the numeric keypad. The `event.shiftKey` property will tell you whether shift was down at the time the key was pressed. Those two events can also check for non-text type keys like the arrow keys, Ctrl, Home, etc.

On the other hand, the [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event gives a keyCode corresponding to the character, so "A" and "a" will give different keyCodes, as will "2" and "@". **So [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) may be better suited to your needs.**

(By the way, this isn't a jQuery thing as such, this is normal behaviour even with "plain" JavaScript, though jQuery attempts to normalise behaviour across different browsers. One such normalisation is that jQuery makes sure that `event.which` will work consistently, so you should use `event.which` to get the code rather than `event.keyCode`.)

Comment: Reasonable background, but `keyCode` is definitely the wrong property in a `keypress` event. I know you go on to say that `which` is the correct property, but I think it would be better to make it clear that `keyCode` should not generally be used with `keypress`. Secondly, if you want a character code corresponding to the character typed, `keypress` is not only better suited than `keydown` or `keyup`, it is the **only** viable way.

Comment: When using jQuery I don't use the actual `.keyCode` property with any of the key events; I always use `.which`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle that matches your exact requirement
http://jsfiddle.net/cSc7r/

You may have to use

```
  String.fromCharCode(key_event.which);
```

or

```
  String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // For IE
```

However if you want to run any event on key press here is a nice plugin to make it very easily.   Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zUc4Z/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to run events when the keys are pressed but you can try
https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Otherwise you can check if the shift key was pressed in the event from your code. Havent seen a library that handles this for you