# jQuery keyCode for angle brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

I'm wondering how to safely see if the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> keys are pressed in jQuery.
It's 226 on my Swedish keyboard, but we're having the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>  keys on the same key, and using shift to select which one.

How can I safely determine which is pressed without having to worry about localization, American keyboard have the keys on two different ones?

Comment: How are you looking at the keyCode?  With jQuery you shouuld probably look at `.which`

Comment: Yep, I'm using `.which` and I can catch it, but I don't know how it will work with other keyboard layouts.

Comment: if you are worried about localization, maybe using the < > are not the best solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the keypress event and the `.which`.

See [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed? A-Z, & @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975703/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed-a-z) for more information.

`.which` gives the character code, as opposed to the keycode. `<` and `>` are symbols and shouldn't be effected by localization as certain letters are.

Comment: Well, I want to know the the keys `<` and `>` are pressed, not if the key with the keyCode 226 is pressed. The US keyCode for `<` for example is 188. So I can't really rely on the keyCode.

Comment: Right, keypress gives you a charCode, not a keyCode. See this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285627/javascript-keycode-vs-charcode-utter-confusion