# Disable keydown for open parenthesis

Tags: jquery, keycode

Am trying to disable open and closed parenthesis for a textbox.

Am succesful in disabling keycode for few characters but not with the one uses SHIFT.

```
 if(event.keyCode == 57 || event.keyCode == 48)
```

disables both 9 ,0 along with open and closed parenthesis

```
if (event.shiftKey) {
            if(event.keyCode == 57 || event.keyCode == 48)
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

how do i diable parenthesis alone and not numbers. what is the correct way.

i dont want to use any plugins

Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/ahized/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ahized/1/edit)). But you should probably use `event.which`, not `event.keyCode`, see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for details.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7975890/2235132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 41)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AVRyc/1/)

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Different keyboard layouts can put the `()` in different places.